# limit the result of a query based on group by

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, inner-query

I'm doing a query on oracle to update a token in a table to do some work on the marked rows.

My problem is that I want to limit the number of rows updated each time to a specific batch size and also to a group by result.

It is kinda hard for me to explain in abstract terms so I'll materialize it.

Say that I have a table called 'staging' with the following fields: (Id, IdFile Grouping, Name, Address1, Address2, Address3, Country, Token)

What I'm trying to do is create a query to do batches with this info.

For each batch, I update the token so that those records are marked to work later on.
I want a batch by file, and each batch has a size limit, so i'm using the rownum to limit it.
Another limitation I have is grouping by batch.

Let's say that my batch size is 5, and If I have 3 and only 3 rows with grouping column filled I have to create a batch with only that 3 rows.

This is my biggest pet peeve as when I'm doing the group by, I get as a result in just one batch results with and without grouping.
(If I had a grouping, I had to see if the destiny address is the same for all rows and create a batch with it.)

Can you help me understand how I have to create this query?

What I'm using right now is:

```
update schema.staging set
token = 'token4'
where id in ( select t.id
               from (
    select stage.id, stage.grouping 
    from (select idFile 
            from (select a.idFile
                  from schema.staging a
                  inner join schema.config c on c.id = a.idcfgpriority
                  where nvl2(a.token,0,1) = 1
                  group by a.idFile, c.order
                  order by c.order desc) files 
            where rownum = 1 ) priorityFile
          inner join schema.staging stage on stage.idFile = priorityFile.idFile
        where nvl2(stage.token,0,1) = 1 
        group by stage.idFile, stage.token, stage.id, grouping sets ( (stage.grouping),
                                                                          (stage.name, stage.Address1,stage.Address2,stage.Address3,stage.Country))
        order by stage.grouping
    ) t
where rownum <= 5 )
```

For the following data:

```
 Id IdFile  Grouping    Name    Address1    Address2    Address3    Country     Token
 ====================================================================================
 1  1       null        Name1   Address1    Address1    Address1    Country     null
 2  1       1           Name1   Address1    Address1    Address1    Country     null
 3  1       1           Name1   Address1    Address1    Address1    Country     null
 4  1       1           Name1   Address1    Address1    Address1    Country     null
 5  1       2           Name1   Address1    Address1    Address1    Country     null
 6  1       2           LALAL   XPTO        Address1    Address1    Country     null
 7  1       null        Name1   Address1    Address1    Address1    Country     null
 8  1       null        Name1   Address1    Address1    Address1    Country     null
 9  1       null        Name1   Address1    Address1    Address1    Country     null
 10 2       null        Name1   Address1    Address1    Address1    Country     null
 11 2       null        Name1   Address1    Address1    Address1    Country     null
 12 2       null        Name1   Address1    Address1    Address1    Country     null
 13 2       null        Name1   Address1    Address1    Address1    Country     null
 14 2       null        Name1   Address1    Address1    Address1    Country     null
 15 2       null        Name1   Address1    Address1    Address1    Country     null
```

I would be expecting 6 batches.

```
batch#1: 1, 7, 8, 9
batch#2: 2, 3, 4
batch#3: 5
batch#4: 6
batch#5: 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
batch#6: 15
```

Sooo... Does anyone have any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that fully understand all requreiments in details, but based on your sample data and desired output following query will work:

```
SELECT dense_rank() over(ORDER BY "IdFile",
                                  "Grouping" nulls FIRST,
                                  "Name" desc,
                                  "Address1",
                                  "Address2",
                                  "Address3",
                                  "Country",
                                  "Token",
                                  row_num) batch_num,
       q.*
  FROM (SELECT trunc((row_number()
                      over(partition BY "IdFile",
                           "Grouping",
                           "Name",
                           "Address1",
                           "Address2",
                           "Address3",
                           "Country",
                           "Token" ORDER BY "Id") - 1) / 5) row_num,
               s.*
          FROM sample s) q
 ORDER BY "Id";
```

Result:

```
| BATCH_NUM | ROW_NUM | ID | IDFILE | GROUPING |  NAME | ADDRESS1 | ADDRESS2 | ADDRESS3 | COUNTRY |  TOKEN |
|-----------|---------|----|--------|----------|-------|----------|----------|----------|---------|--------|
|         1 |       0 |  1 |      1 |   (null) | Name1 | Address1 | Address1 | Address1 | Country | (null) |
|         2 |       0 |  2 |      1 |        1 | Name1 | Address1 | Address1 | Address1 | Country | (null) |
|         2 |       0 |  3 |      1 |        1 | Name1 | Address1 | Address1 | Address1 | Country | (null) |
|         2 |       0 |  4 |      1 |        1 | Name1 | Address1 | Address1 | Address1 | Country | (null) |
|         3 |       0 |  5 |      1 |        2 | Name1 | Address1 | Address1 | Address1 | Country | (null) |
|         4 |       0 |  6 |      1 |        2 | LALAL |     XPTO | Address1 | Address1 | Country | (null) |
|         1 |       0 |  7 |      1 |   (null) | Name1 | Address1 | Address1 | Address1 | Country | (null) |
|         1 |       0 |  8 |      1 |   (null) | Name1 | Address1 | Address1 | Address1 | Country | (null) |
|         1 |       0 |  9 |      1 |   (null) | Name1 | Address1 | Address1 | Address1 | Country | (null) |
|         5 |       0 | 10 |      2 |   (null) | Name1 | Address1 | Address1 | Address1 | Country | (null) |
|         5 |       0 | 11 |      2 |   (null) | Name1 | Address1 | Address1 | Address1 | Country | (null) |
|         5 |       0 | 12 |      2 |   (null) | Name1 | Address1 | Address1 | Address1 | Country | (null) |
|         5 |       0 | 13 |      2 |   (null) | Name1 | Address1 | Address1 | Address1 | Country | (null) |
|         5 |       0 | 14 |      2 |   (null) | Name1 | Address1 | Address1 | Address1 | Country | (null) |
|         6 |       1 | 15 |      2 |   (null) | Name1 | Address1 | Address1 | Address1 | Country | (null) |
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/86f0e/17/0).

I have played a little with ordering to fully simulate batch numbering you have provided. You can safely discard `desc` and `nulls FIRST` parts. Let me know if the query solves your problem.

Comment: I had to make some adjustments but your query has helped me to overcome my problem! Thanks!